# Custom attributes on a user delta call to the Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have some custom attributes configured to sync with an on-premise Active Directory. These attributes are syncing correctly and can be accessed via the following call to the Microsoft Graph.

```http
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,givenName,surname,mail,jobTitle,department,companyName,mobilePhone,businessPhones,officeLocation,accountEnabled,extension_<GUID_REMOVED>_ipPhone,extension_<GUID_REMOVED>_division

{
  "id": "<GUID_REMOVED>",
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "businessPhones": [],
  "companyName": "Foobar",
  "department": "IT",
  "displayName": "Foo Bar",
  "givenName": "Foo",
  "jobTitle": "Labourer",
  "mail": "foo.bar@foobar.com",
  "mobilePhone": null,
  "officeLocation": "Site",
  "surname": "Foo",
  "extension_<GUID_REMOVED>_division": "Group"
}
```

If I make the same call using the delta query

```http
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=id,displayName,givenName,surname,mail,jobTitle,department,companyName,mobilePhone,businessPhones,officeLocation,accountEnabled,extension_<GUID_REMOVED>_ipPhone,extension_<GUID_REMOVED>_division

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "businessPhones": [],
  "companyName": "Foobar",
  "department": "IT",
  "displayName": "Foo Bar",
  "givenName": "Foo",
  "jobTitle": "Labourer",
  "mail": "foo.bar@foobar.com",
  "mobilePhone": null,
  "officeLocation": "Site",
  "surname": "Bar",
  "id": "<GUID_REMOVED>"
}
```

The custom attributes are not shown in the result.

Can anyone help? Is there a reason for this or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the Delta query. From the [Known Issues documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#delta-query):

> **Delta query**
>
> - OData context is sometimes returned incorrectly when tracking changes to relationships.
> - Schema extensions (legacy) are not returned with $select statement, but are returned without $select.
> - **Clients cannot track changes to open extensions or registered schema extensions.**